# wordpress action form doesn't work

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, action, contacts

I have a page-contact.php (i have my custom form)

```
            <form id="contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post" action="">
                <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="name"/>
                <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="email"/>
                <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="message" 
                placeholder="message"> </textarea>
                <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="send"/>
            </form>
```

I have a my email_process.php (

```
<?php

$to        = 'info@domain.com';
$subject   = $_POST['name'];
$email     = $_POST['email'];
$body      = $_POST['message'];
$headers   = 'From: '.$email;
$mailCheck = mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);

if($mailCheck) echo 1;

?>
```

I have also a js file for echo my success message and error message. The js form seems to work. but email_process.php is not working. For hand coded html without wordpress, the form action work "email_process.php"
I think wordpress handle the code different. Can someone help me with this?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alertAnswer();
});


var check = 1;

function alertAnswer(){
$('#contact-form').submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    checkFormFill();
    if(check == false) alert("you didn't answer my form");
    else sendMessage();
});
}

function checkFormFill() {
check = 1;
$('#contact-form input[type="text"]').each(function(){
    if($(this).val().length < 3) check = false 
}) 

if($('#contact-form textarea').val().length < 3) check = false 
}

function eraseFormData() {
$('#contact-form input[type="text"]').each(function(){
    $(this).val('');
}) 

$('#contact-form textarea').val(''); 
}

function sendMessage() {
$.post('email_process.php',
    {
        name: $('input[name="name"]').val(),
        email: $('input[name="email"]').val(),
        message: $('textarea[name="message"]').val()
    },
    function(data) {
    if(data == 1) {
        $('#sendMessage').text("Thanks for contacting us. 
        We\'ll get back to you     shortly.");
        $('#sendMessage').css("margin-top","15px"); 
        eraseFormData(); 
    } 
    else $('#sendMessage').text("Sorry, an error occured. 
    Please try again!");
});
}
```

Comment: With Wordpress you'll need to create an AJAX hook: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_%28action%29

Comment: Add `email_process.php` value inside your action attribute in `<form>` tag, like this: `<form id="contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post" action="email_process.php`">`

Comment: i did try 
<form id="contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post" action="email_process.php"> , but not working....

Comment: is ajax hook for the email_process or for js file?

Comment: You might save a lot of time by installing the 'contact form 7' plugin, its good and lightweight and you can add the forms shortcode where ever you want to display your form

Answer (score 0):

In wordpress there are lot of flexible plugins for you to create forms and submit without any hardcoding. But if you would like to know how this is done in wordpress you need to use `wp_mail( $to, $subject, $body, $headers );`. Try the following.

Add this to your functions.php

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_send_email', 'send_email');

function send_email() {
  // check the nonce before submit the form 
  $nonce = check_ajax_referer( 'ajax_nonce', 'nonce' );
    if($nonce) {

              $to        = 'info@domain.com';
                 $subject   = $_POST['name'];
               $email     = $_POST['email'];
              $body = $_POST['message'];
           $headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

              wp_mail( $to, $subject, $body, $headers );
       }

}
```

Create a new file and add the following code and name it as form.js

```
(function($) {
    jQuery( "form#contact-form" ).submit(function( event ) {
        name: jQuery('input[name="name"]').val();
        email: jQuery('input[name="email"]').val();
        message: jQuery('textarea[name="message"]').val();
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: ajax_object.url,
            data: nonce:ajax_object.nonce + 'action=send_email&name='+name+'&email='+email+'&message='+message,
            dataType: 'JSON',
            type: 'POST',
            success:function(data){
                jQuery('#sendMessage').text("Thanks for contacting us. We\'ll get back to you     shortly.");
            }
        });
    });
}(jQuery));
```

Then include the following code in to your funtions.php as well to enqueue script. and make sure you define the correct path for the form.js file.

```
/* Enqueue Scripts */
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_enqueue_scripts', 99);
function custom_enqueue_scripts(){

    wp_register_script('custom-form', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/form.js', 'jquery', '2.6.2');
    wp_enqueue_script('custom-form');
    // need to localize the script and add nonce because of spam submissions
    wp_localize_script('custom-form', 'ajax_object', array('url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'), 'nonce' => wp_create_nonce("ajax_form_nonce")));
}
```

Again i have not included validation funtions here. You can include them in same form.js  file.

Comment: do I have to create a JSON file for the jquery?

Comment: you only need add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_send_email', 'send_email'); for frontend submission. but other one for backend. but yeah in  your case  just wp_ajax_nopriv action is enough

Comment: No no need json file. Wordpress api handles everythiing in its own

Comment: do I have to create a function for it? where should i put the ready function? i don't get it.

$(document).ready(function(){

 
});

Comment: Im bit busy right now. i'll update my answer with all necessary coding sometime today for you. So you will understand it :)

Comment: Thank you Jason.. appreciate it... :)

Comment: i was waiting for your reply :)

Comment: hey sorry.. was really busy finishing some projects. 12 simultaneous projects. :) i'll update this today for sure

Comment: see the console and let me know if there is any errors. i dont see any issue with the code but might be conflicting with something.

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
embed.js:787 Consider using 'dppx' units, as in CSS 'dpi' means dots-per-CSS-inch, not dots-per-physical-inch, so does not correspond to the actual 'dpi' of a screen. In media query expression: (min-resolution: 144dpi)
embed.js:788 Consider using 'dppx' units, as in CSS 'dpi' means dots-per-CSS-inch, not dots-per-physical-inch, so does not correspond to the actual 'dpi' of a screen. In media query expression: (min-resolution: 144dpi)

Comment: http://localhost:8888/wordpress/contact/email_process.php Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: that what i have for console. do u know the problem?

Comment: email: jQuery('input[name="email"]').val(),

uncaught syntaxerror : unexpected token:

Comment: You need to use ; instead , at the end of .val() and remve your ld script for the frm before you implement my new functions.

Comment: Please check the updated answer, If its still not working just add this action too 
`add_action('wp_ajax_send_email', 'send_email');`
its working for me sometimes

Comment: i still have this problem! I remove the , at the end of .val() and replace it with ;    when I submit , it bring me to index page and the title is page not found. What do mean with remove ld script? Console problem :

Consider using 'dppx' units, as in CSS 'dpi' means dots-per-CSS-inch, not dots-per-physical-inch, so does not correspond to the actual 'dpi' of a screen. In media query expression: (min-resolution: 144dpi)

Comment: I remove the , at the end of .val() and replace it with ;   the Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :  problem solve, but i still have this problem!  when I submit , it bring me to index page and the title is page not found. What do mean with remove ld script? Console problem :

Consider using 'dppx' units, as in CSS 'dpi' means dots-per-CSS-inch, not dots-per-physical-inch, so does not correspond to the actual 'dpi' of a screen. In media query expression: (min-resolution: 144dpi)

Comment: The Console problem is for my map : 
--------------------------
Consider using 'dppx' units, as in CSS 'dpi' means dots-per-CSS-inch, not dots-per-physical-inch, so does not correspond to the actual 'dpi' of a screen. In media query expression: (min-resolution: 144dpi)
----------------
i don't think that makes my form not working.
so why is my form not working :(

Comment: That has nothing to do with it. cant really say why it is not wokring beacuse it has to work. i didnt ask you to remove whole .val() part. i just asked u to remove the comma and replace it with semi coloumn. if u really need to get this working contact me in skype 'lahirunanayakkara'. if u can give me teamviewer access to your files i'll look at it and fix t for u